# Cómo puedo Guardar la ruta de un Uri en una base de datos y recuperarlo luego

Tags: android, uri

El problema principal es que seleccionó una imagen de galería , luego este Uri se lo asignó a un imageview, hasta aquí todo bien. Entonces guardo la ruta de ese Uri en un String

String uri_image = Uri_Img.toString();

Si el estribo lo por intent.putextra y lo recupero en otra actividad y selo asignó a un imageview me funciona. Pero si este String lo guardo en una tabla de base de datos y lo recupero e intento colocarse lo a un imageview no funciona....

Comment: podrias poner todo el bloque de codigo que utilizas para guardar ese uri ? gracias

Comment: podrias guardarlo tambien en una carpeta privada de tu app y solo guardar el nombre del archivo en la base de datos :D.

Comment: y que mensaje de error te muestra al intentarlo el log? Mas aún, al guardarlo en la base de datos con que tipo de campo lo haces?

Comment: No me muestra erro... Sino que guardo convierto el Uri a String rutaUri = Uri.toString() y eso guarda context://media/etc ... Y eso lo mando a la base de datos luego cuando lo recupero solo no coloca la imagen en el textview , en cambio si convierto la Uri a String y la paso a otra actividad por puta extra si funciona... El problema está en que si la recupero de la base de datos no se que ocurre